# Difference between a translationary invariant and a stable distribution

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, stable-distribution

I understand that a stable distribution is a distribution whose linear combination of two independent random variables with this distribution has the same distribution (ignoring location and scale parameters). I haven't found a specific definition for a translationary invariant distribution but it seems its usage in scientific papers is equivalent to a stable distribution. Is there any particular difference between the two?